# Play Framework: type mismatch JsValue / JsValueWrapper

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I need to convert this JSON

```
{ "matchItem": { "collection": { "fieldName": [ "value1", "value2" ] } } }
```

to this MongoDB projection:

```
{ "collection": { "$elemMatch": { "fieldName": "value1", "fieldName": "value2" } }
```

Here below is my code:

```
def toProjection(json: JsValue) = {
  json.getOpt(__ \ "matchItem").map { value =>
    val obj = value.as[JsObject]
    for (key <- obj.keys) { obj.getOpt(__ \ key).map { matchObj =>
      for (matchKey <- matchObj.as[JsObject].keys) { matchObj.getOpt(__ \ matchKey).map { items =>
        val fields = items.as[Seq[JsValue]].map(item => (matchKey -> item))
        seq += key -> Json.obj("$elemMatch" -> Json.obj(fields))
      }}
    }}
  }
  if (seq.length > 0) JsObject(seq) else json
}

val json = """{ "matchItem": { "collection": { "fieldName": [ "value1", "value2" ] } } }"""
val proj = toProjection(json)
```

This code does not compile and I always get the following error message:

```
[error] /home/j3d/Projects/test/app/services/Test.scala:82: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Seq[(String, play.api.libs.json.JsValue)]
[error]  required: (String, play.api.libs.json.Json.JsValueWrapper)
[error]                 seq += fieldMaps.fromPublic(key) -> Json.obj("$elemMatch" -> Json.obj(fields))
[error]                                                                                       ^
```

I'm a bit lost. I know `Json.obj` is a helper method to build `JsObject` instances:

```
JsObject(Seq(
  "key1" -> JsString("value1"),
  "key2" -> JsString("value2")
  ...
))
```

... is equivalent to:

```
Json.obj("key1" -> "value1", "key2" -> "value2")
```

In my code above, the `fields` value is a `Seq[(String, play.api.libs.json.JsValue)]`... so I don't understand why it doesn't work. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I see there is some discussion on JsValue and JsValueWrapper [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/Bs5pEy2nAzs) that might be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
def toProjection(json: JsValue) = {
  json.getOpt(__ \ "matchItem").map { value =>
    val obj = value.as[JsObject]
    for (key <- obj.keys) { obj.getOpt(__ \ key).map { matchObj =>
      for (matchKey <- matchObj.as[JsObject].keys) { matchObj.getOpt(__ \ matchKey).map { items =>
        val fields = items.as[Seq[JsValue]].map(item => (matchKey -> item))
     // seq += key -> Json.obj("$elemMatch" -> Json.obj(fields))
        seq += key -> Json.obj("$elemMatch" -> JsObject(fields))
      }}
    }}
  }
  if (seq.length > 0) JsObject(seq) else json
}
```

Replacing `Json.obj(fields)` with `JsObject(fields)` does the trick.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up here after implementing my own solution and thinking there must be an easier way. Looks like there isnt. And here's yet another solution that appears to work:

```
def flatten(update: JsObject): JsObject = {
    def f(key: String, value: JsValue): Seq[(String, JsValue)] = {
      value match {
        case o: JsObject => o.fields.flatMap(kv => f(s"$key.${kv._1}", kv._2))
        case v: JsValue => Seq(key -> v)
      }
    }
    JsObject(update.fields.flatMap(kv => f(kv._1, kv._2)))
  }
```